# Is it beneficial to integrate requirejs with angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I have used requirejs with jquery and javascript till now. I have seen so many benefits of it.

Now I want to use angular js in my new project so I want to know that is it beneficial to use require js with angular js.

Thanks.

Comment: beneficial is extremely objective, what do you need from both of them? why wouldn't it be beneficial?

Comment: I want to know that if I integrate both of this then it will work fine or not? Is there any technical issue in combining both in a project?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W13qDdJDHp8&feature=player_detailpage#t=3301s RequireJS might be used instead of angular.module in the next version of AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

I often use them both in one project. I even created simple boilerplate project [here](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs). RequireJs optimization is also included.

My opinion - RequireJs is beneficial for large scale projects.

Answer (score 0):

The `AngularJS` app that would most benefit from `RequireJS` is the one where there are lots of logics (JS files) that are sporadically used by your users.  Another instance is when you have an offline app but require 3rd party library such as `Google Maps API`.  You would need a async loader such as `RequireJS` to allow you to first check if you are online and then proceed to load the 3rd party library.

If your app is simple and all the logic are needed on the main page, `RequireJS` brings very little benefit and would make your page load a bit slower due to the slight overhead of `RequireJS`.

In case you wish to proceed with `RequireJS`, I created `angularAMD` that simplifies the integration:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/